# Perl refuses to run scripts

Tags: perl

I'm using Perl 5.14.2 on Cygwin, and suddenly it refuses to run the simplest of scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "hello world!\n";
```

Trying to execute this causes Perl to do absolutely nothing, and neither does `$?` contain anything:

```
Administrator@Windows7 /cygdrive/d/Development/Perl
$ perl helloworld.plx

Administrator@Windows7 /cygdrive/d/Development/Perl
$ echo $?
0
```

However, I have written more complex scripts earlier, and they do run:

```
Administrator@Windows7 /cygdrive/d/Development/Perl
$ perl siteinfo.plx

Site info : google.com
________________________________________________________________________________
Whois : ( ... whois info printed here ...)
hpHosts : Not Listed
```

I really can't understand what is exactly going on here. I've tried reinstalling Perl but with no luck.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Does it work from command line? `perl -e "print qq{hello world!\n};"`

Comment: what happens in the perl debugger, ie ``perl -d helloworld.plx``??

Comment: @mpapec, your command works successfully.
@Vorsprung, the debugger reports that `Debugged program terminated`.

Comment: `$?` returning `0` illustrates that the previous command was successful.

Comment: can you run the command from the Windows command line instead of a Cygwin shell?

Comment: @golimar, it has the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this turns out to be very dumb:

My text editor was set to churn out text files with Macintosh EOL format. Converting it to Unix/Windows format corrects the issue.

However, one thing that I found strange was that Perl would not notify of this issue, and instead it simply did nothing.

Comment: Since the file had no recognizable line endings, the Perl interpreter was treating the entire file as a shebang (`#!` line) and ignoring it. An empty Perl script quietly does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use B::Deparse to see how perl parses your program

```
  $ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e ""
  -e syntax OK

  $ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e "#!/usr/bin/perl -- die 666; "
  -e syntax OK

  $ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e "die 666; "
  die(666);
  -e syntax OK
```